# How to install apps from GooglePlay from Activity ? Android

Tags: android

I made a simple code that will download a app from Google Play.I tried
the code  and tested it on real device but I got an error called "No application can perform this action."I declared android.permission.INTERNET in the manifest, but still doesn't work.
I would be glad if you can help me out.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("market://developer?*/urlofgoogleplay*/"));
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(i,"Launch Market");
        startActivity(chooser);
```

Comment: Does the real device have the Play Store on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void linkGooglePlay(Context context) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + context.getPackageName());
    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    try {
      context.startActivity(goToMarket);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right syntax:

```
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + app_package));
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html)